# Xpath: obtain href if contains specific word

Tags: python, regex, xpath, href

**Set up**

I'm extracting hrefs from a page using the following xpath,

```
'/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/p[1]/a/@href'
```

which gives me a list of hrefs looking like,

```
['#',
 'showv2.php?p=Glasgow City&t=Anderston',
 'showv2.php?p=Glasgow City&t=Anniesland',
 'showv2.php?p=Glasgow City&t=Ashfield',
 '#',
 'showv2.php?p=Glasgow City&t=Baillieston',
           ⋮
'showv2.php?p=Glasgow City&t=Yoker']
```

---

**Problem**

I'm not interested in the `'#'` hrefs. All the hrefs I am interested in contain `Glasgow`. How do I select only the hrefs containing `Glasgow`?

I've seen answers regarding regex with `'id'` etc, but not with href. Those answers do not seem to work with href.

I've seen answers regarding regex with beginning or ending of a href, but I'd like to be able to regex on 'containing' a word.

Comment: Try `'/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/p[1]/a[contains(@href, "Glasgow")]/@href'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks! I adjusted your `'Glasgow'` to `"Glasgow"`, then it worked. With `''` I got a syntax error in the Scrapy Shell.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the single quotes used to define the string literal, and changed my comment a second before yours appeared. I posted an answer below.

Comment: Seen it! I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `contains(@href, 'Glasgow')` "restriction" on the `a` elements:

```
'/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/p[1]/a[contains(@href, "Glasgow")]/@href'
```

Then, it will only find those `<a>`s under the specified path that contain `Glasgow` inside their `href` attribute values.